# Inset data into table that were connected to another table by a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a problem where i have created two tables in MYSQL where one table is bookticket and the other table is the customer table.

customer table
**customer_id(pk)**,fullname,matric_id,ic_no,gender,address,postcode,state,hp_number,tel_number,username,password,repeatpassword.

booktickect table
**ticket_id(pk)**,liner,direction,from,f_date,f_time,destination,t_date,t_time,total_price,**customer_id(fk)**

So now after i have registered and login as a user,how can i create a php code to enter the bookticket data where it will be automatically assigned to the current logged in user based on the customer_id foreign key that i have implemented in my bookticket table.Thank you in advance.

Sorry for not providing my php code in my earlier post.I have edited my question. :)

```
<?php

 echo "<h1>Booking</h1>";

 $submit = $_POST['submit'];

 //ticket booking form data

 $liner     = strip_tags($_POST['liner']); 
 $direction     = strip_tags($_POST['direction']); 
 $from      = strip_tags($_POST['from']); 
 $f_date        = strip_tags($_POST['f_date']); 
 $f_time        = strip_tags($_POST['f_time']); 
 $destination   = strip_tags($_POST['destination']); 
 $t_date        = strip_tags($_POST['t_date']); 
 $t_time        = strip_tags($_POST['t_time']); 
 $total_price       = strip_tags($_POST['txttotal']);

 if ($submit)
 {  

 //check the direction selected by user

if ($direction == "return")
{

//check for existance

    if($liner && $direction && $from && $f_date && $f_time && $destination && $t_date &&      $t_time && $total_price )
            {

             $connect  = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"cc11205","11205");
                mysql_select_db("cc11205");

              $queryreg = mysql_query("

              INSERT INTO bookticket VALUES ('','$liner','$direction','$from','$f_date','$f_time','$destination','$t_date','$t_time','$total_price','');


              ");

              die("Your booking details has been succesfully inserted into the database.Please <a href='customer.php'>Click here</a> to go to the main page to view your booking");

            }

        else 

            echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

}
else if ($direction == "oneway")
{
    if($liner && $direction && $from && $f_date && $f_time && $destination && $total_price  )
            {
               $connect  = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"cc11205","11205");
                mysql_select_db("cc11205");

              $queryreg = mysql_query("

              INSERT INTO bookticket VALUES ('','$liner','$direction','$from','$f_date','$f_time','$destination','','','$total_price','');


              ");
              die("Your booking details has been succesfully inserted into the database.Please <a href='customer.php'>Click here</a> to go to the main page to view your booking");

            }
        else 
            echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

}
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! It's a very broad question. You need to narrow it down to what exactly you don't understand or have problem with. If you just want someone to write code for you StackOverflow is wrong place to ask, you can try freelance sites.

Comment: Mr.peterm I'm very sorry. i have reedited the question.If there is any mistakes again,do let me know.Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i assume you want to know how to obtain the generated key of the first query to the `customer` table. you can use `mysql_insert_id` for this. below is an example.

```
$rs = mysql_query($insert_sql_for_customer);
$customer_id = mysql_insert_id();

$booking_sql = "INSERT INTO bookticket (customer_id, field1, field2, ...) VALUES ($customer_id, $val1, $val2, ...);
mysql_query($booking_sql);
```

Comment: So will the code match with the primary key(customer_id in customer table) to the foreign key(customer_id in the bookticket table).

Comment: thank you Mr @DevZer0 i've tried this and it worked.             `$query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$customer_id= $row['customer_id'];}
$username =$_SESSION['username'];
$booking_sql = "INSERT INTO bookticket VALUES ('','$customer_id','$liner','$direction','$from','$f_date','$f_time','$destination','$t_date','$t_time','$total_price')";
mysql_query($booking_sql);
      

            
 }
 else
{echo "Invalid user";}`